# How to write a SPARK map function to return a substring in JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a JavaRDD object and want to create another new JavaRDD object by selecting a substring of the original one. How to achieve that?

```
 // Read input_train data
    logger.info("start to read file");
    JavaRDD<String> inputDataRaw= sc.textFile(input_train);
```

There inputDataRaw.first() is something like: "apple1; apple2;" (say String s1)

I want to JavaRDD with each line consisting of "apple1" only, i.e.,:

```
  String s2 = s1.substring(0, 6)
```

Comment: use `rdd.map()` - also check the docs. This is a basic operation on Spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

Comment: @maasg thanks for the pointer. can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

```
 JavaRDD<String> inputDataRaw= sc.textFile(input_train);
 inputDataRaw.new Function<String>() {
 public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
     return arg0.substring(0,6);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simple option. I included the newer JDK8 lambda syntax as well as the older JDK6 compatible syntax:

```
    JavaRDD<String> inputDataRaw = sc.textFile("file.txt");

    JavaRDD<String> mapped_jdk8 = inputDataRaw.map(s -> s.substring(0, 6));

    JavaRDD<String> mapped_jdk6 = inputDataRaw.map(new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(String s) throws Exception {
            return s.substring(0, 6);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you help on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332897/how-to-add-new-column-to-datasetrow-using-map-function-on-the-dataset

Answer (score 0):

I think substring is not a good idea to grab the first object from a line.

```
substring(0,6) # this will help only when first object is of fixed size.
```

Instead first split the line with ; (comma) and grab the first index

```
JavaRDD<String> inputDataRaw = sc.textFile("file.txt");

JavaRDD<String> mapped_jdk8 = inputDataRaw.map(s -> s.split(";")).map(r -> r(0));
```

try r[0]  if you get any syntax error in java, I've not tried lambda in java but i do scala only