# How to add new column to Spark dataframe using a Java UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataset<Row> inputDS` which has 4 columns namely `Id, List<long> time, List<String> value, aggregateType` I want to add one more column to the `Dataset` `value_new` using map function, that map function takes columns `time` , `value` and `aggregateType` passes that to a function `getAggregate(String aggregateType, List<long> time, List<String> value)` and return a double value on processing the parameters. The `Double` value returned by the method `getAggregate` will be the new column value i.e value of `value_new`

**Dataset inputDS**

```
 +------+---+-----------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
 |    Id| value         |     time                                   |aggregateType  |
 +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
 |0001  |  [1.5,3.4,4.5]| [1551502200000,1551502200000,1551502200000] | Sum           |
 +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

**Expected Dataset outputDS**

```
 +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------+
 |    Id| value         |     time                                    |aggregateType  | value_new |
 +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------+
 |0001  |  [1.5,3.4,4.5]| [1551502200000,1551502200000,1551502200000] | Sum           |   9.4     |
 +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

**Code I tried**.

```
 inputDS.withColumn("value_new",functions.lit(inputDS.map(new MapFunction<Row,Double>(){

 public double call(Row row){
 String aggregateType = row.getAS("aggregateType");
 List<long> timeList = row.getList("time");
 List<long> valueList= row.getList("value");  

 return  getAggregate(aggregateType ,timeList,valueList);    

 }}),Encoders.DOUBLE())));
```

**ERROR**

```
 Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset [value:double]
```

**Note** Sorry if I used `map` function wrongly and please suggest me if there is any workaround.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are trying to create a function literal (`lit()`) using the result of `Dataset.map()`, which you can see in docs is a Dataset. You can see in the API for `Dataset.withColumn()` that you need a argument that is a column.

It seems like you need to create a user-defined function. Take a look at [How do I call a UDF on a Spark DataFrame using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348058/how-do-i-call-a-udf-on-a-spark-dataframe-using-java)